# Catch Print event in C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, printing

what I want is when I print a document (which is a record in the database) this document can't get updated by the user anymore, so i thought if only I can capture the printing event and set a print field to true for that record so when the user tries to update the operation will be canceled. Do you guys have any ideas how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Seeing your tags (specifically `asp.net`), I assume you need this event to somehow come from a user who has the record open on a webpage and then prints the page using his browser?

Comment: Printing on web client is much more complecated. The ways that i know and have implement tocatch print and stuff like errors is throuth silverlight or through activex. These things of course they playing on ie.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
void PrintDocument(IDocument document)
{
    if (document.IsPrinted)
    {
        return;
    }

    // now print the document

    document.IsPrinted = true;

    SaveDocument(document);
}
```

If you want more sensible code, or do not how to implement this in your project, perhaps your relevant code and the parts you're having trouble with will help.

Comment: @kostasch. I don't know what you mean, this code doesn't print anything, it outlines the general idea of only letting an action take place once based on a flag that gets stored somewhere. OP cannot directly use this code, but learn from the idea.

Comment: Yes you r right, i will change my comment. But this piece of code refer to server. If client do the print you cannot catch the event through the above.

Comment: Then OP should ask _"How do I prevent a user to print something from the browser"_, to which the answer is _"You don't"_.

Comment: Yes, but can you catch the event of client printing by the above? I think no. You can not catch the printing event from client on server side by this.

Comment: @kostasch. I am aknowledging what you said: that you cannot prevent a print event in a web browser from the server. I did not say that my code did that.

Comment: I did't said about preventing. I said about event catch. I said that your code refer to server side and printing in web refer (must of the times) to the client which in order to catch printing event you have to use much code(activex,silverlight).

Comment: @kostasch. again, I do understand your point. This code however is about the general idea, I did not post it as _"this code will let you catch printing event in browser"_, as that was not OP's question. Thanks.